# Mysql with 2 foreign key

Tags: mysql

[image]

I am making a DB for categories of an ads website. In the database there would be the main categorie like (computer, construction ... ) in the computer categorie there would be a sub level of categorie like programmer and in the sub categorie there would be another sub categorie like programmer type A, programmer Type B.

In my adsCategorie table i have 2 foreign key, 1 go to the first sub categorie and one go to the second sub categorie but only 1 can be not null. Does I am allowed to do that or there is another way ?

Sorry about my poor english

Comment: yes i think there is nothing to worry abt

Comment: Does its the best way to do it or there is place for improvement ?

Comment: to add reference to another you have to add relationship between two table so you have to define foreign key